# SVN Info command different when run from Java than in terminal

Tags: java, svn, exec, runtime.exec

I'm using the `svn` command from Java to get info about a working copy.

```
final Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[]{"svn","info","--xml","/path/to/wc"}
);
ByteStreams.copy(exec.getErrorStream(), System.err);
// ... more code to read output
```

This gives the error output

```
/path/to/wc
:  (Not a versioned resource)
```

However, if I run the same command in a terminal window, I get the output I want. I also tried to rule out the environment when running in a terminal:

```
env -i svn info --xml /path/to/wc
```

But the output is still correct. Why does it behave differently when run from Java?

Comment: Does your real "path to wc" contain spaces?

Comment: @SeanBright No it doesn't, but even if it did, shouldn't passing the command as an array prevent that from causing any errors?

Comment: are you running the svn command from the terminal in the working directory?

Comment: @jtahlborn No, the working directory of the terminal is my home dir, which is not the working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real `/path/to/wc` had a newline at the end of it. If I were more familiar with SVN error output, I could have seen it:

```
/path/to/wc
:  (Not a versioned resource)
```

Note the newline before the `:`

I accidentally found this by replacing an earlier `exec("readlink -m " + path)` by the pure Java `path.getCanonicalName()`.